# How can i make sure that all punctuation isn't encrypted?

Tags: python, encryption

```
        for n in range(0, len(plaintext)):
            if plaintext[n] == ' ':
                new = ord(plaintext[n])
            else:
                new = ord(plaintext[n]) + ord(key[n%len(key)]) - 65
                if new > 90:
```

So i want to know how i can make sure that all punctuation isn't encrypted and only letters are encrypted? I know that this isn't a good way to encrypt but it is for a school project so it would be great if someone can help me. Also when i decrypt it doesn't decrypt properly and sometimes forgets full stops and stuff how can i fix this? Thanks.

Comment: It's better to separate it into 2 questions. The first one might be related to regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define all punctuation;

```
punctuation = " ',.;:.!?\r\n"
```

Replace *all* instances of

```
if plaintext[n] == ' ':
```

by

```
if plaintext[n] in punctuation:
```

**Addition**

While your code is functional, it doesn't use a lot of the powerful tools that Python puts at your disposal. Let me illustrate. The encryption/decryption (with punctuation stripped from the text) could be done like this, using list comprehensions;

```
In [42]: plaintext = 'THISISAPLAINTEXT' # Your algorithm only works for capitals.

In [43]: key = 'SPAMEGGS'

In [44]: count = int(len(plaintext)/len(key))+1

In [45]: stretchedkey = [ord(c) for c in key*count]

In [46]: # Encryption

In [47]: plainnum = [ord(c) for c in plaintext]

In [48]: ciphernum = [a+b-65 for a, b in zip(plainnum, stretchedkey)]

In [49]: ciphertext = ''.join([chr(c) if c <= 90 else chr(c-26) for c in ciphernum])

In [50]: ciphertext
Out[50]: 'LWIEMYGHDPIZXKDL'

In [51]: # Decryption

In [52]: ciphernum = [ord(c) for c in ciphertext]

In [53]: decryptnum = [a-b+65 for a, b in zip(ciphernum, stretchedkey)]

In [54]: decrypt = ''.join([chr(c) if c >= 65 else chr(c+26) for c in decryptnum])

In [55]: decrypt
Out[55]: 'THISISAPLAINTEXT'
```

Some explanations.

A list comprehension can convert a string to a list of  one character strings;

```
In [69]: [c for c in 'THISISATEXT']
Out[69]: ['T', 'H', 'I', 'S', 'I', 'S', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'X', 'T']
```

Or to a list of character values;

```
In [70]: [ord(c) for c in 'THISISATEXT']
Out[70]: [84, 72, 73, 83, 73, 83, 65, 84, 69, 88, 84]
```

You can even strip out punctuation while you do that.

```
In [80]: [c for c in 'THIS IS A TEXT.' if c not in ' .']
Out[80]: ['T', 'H', 'I', 'S', 'I', 'S', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'X', 'T']
```

The `zip` built-in lets you iterate over combinations of lists;

```
In [73]: p = [ord(c) for c in 'THISISATEXT']

In [74]: q = [ord(c) for c in 'SPAMEGGSSPAMEGGS']

In [77]: p
Out[77]: [84, 72, 73, 83, 73, 83, 65, 84, 69, 88, 84]

In [78]: q
Out[78]: [83, 80, 65, 77, 69, 71, 71, 83, 83, 80, 65, 77, 69, 71, 71, 83]

In [79]: [a+b for a, b in zip(p, q)]
Out[79]: [167, 152, 138, 160, 142, 154, 136, 167, 152, 168, 149]
```

Hint:

Make a list of all the punctuation in a string, with its index.

```
In [82]: [(n, c) for n, c in enumerate('THIS IS A TEXT.') if c in ' .']
Out[82]: [(4, ' '), (7, ' '), (9, ' '), (14, '.')]
```

Comment: That is not very informative. Can you edit your question and add an example input/output?

Comment: how do i allow it to not do apostrophes ( ' )?